# embedding Javascript in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, autologin, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm currently developing an app the stores password (like a password manager). One of its features is to allow user to make an auto login to a web browser of that device. I was able to make it work using UIWebView and WKWebView but can't find a way to make it work using SFSafariViewController. I read few documentations and blogs about it and even read the SFSafariViewController.h but there's no clue in there that can lead me to the function that I wanted. I want to know how to do a "evaluateJavaScript"-a-like function in SFSafariViewController or if its not possible, do you guys have other suggestions on how to achieve this?

Note: I'm using Objective-C.

Thanks in advance!
Happy coding!

Comment: I don’t think this is possible — `SFSafariViewController` Apple doesn’t allow interaction: “The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app” [(docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html).

Comment: Is there other way to implement auto login from app to a specified URL? I'm thinking of putting up a web API to my server and do the trick there and post it to the login URL of the site where I wanted to login. Is that possible?

Comment: You should just use `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`. If you want to log in with a system view, you can use [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to send a POST request to your server.

Comment: Yup, I tried that and even made that work. But my client wanted it to open Safari after logging in. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes! Just call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL here"]]`.

Comment: That will call the Safari. But the authenticated session won't be passed right? I mean if I requested sample.com as openURL it will be treated as different instance and will still ask for the user's credentials

Comment: You could (for example) pass an authentication token in the URL that would transfer the session, then be invalidated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102632/discussion-between-mcube-and-j-f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SFSafariViewControllers` are sandboxed. As they are essentially Safari, and have access to cookies. It would be a security risk to allow any app to access these.

However, if the web-service you want the user to sign in to is yours, you can setup a API and a custom URL scheme.

[Follow this documentation](https://github.com/mackuba/SafariAutoLoginTest).

If you are trying to store passwords etc from sites you don't maintain then unfortunately, this is not possible using the `SFSafariViewController`.

Hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll check this out later. :)